# Enable AES encryption via ATA password on Samsung Evo 840 with data already on the drive?

Tags: ssd, encryption, aes

Does the Evo 840 support changing the AES key (more or less) on the fly (in my case from "no key" to "my key")? I don't mind if it takes an hour to encipher the data as long as I don't have to re-install the OS.

In case the answer is no: I guess creating a disk image, wipe ssd, set ATA password and then restore backup will work?

Comment: In short the answer is no. See this existing answer on how to encrypt your drive: http://superuser.com/questions/700009/how-do-i-encrypt-samsung-840-ssd-with-bitlocker/700236#700236

Comment: hm, worked fine for me (but forgot about this question here). I just set the ATA password; ok, the actual AES key stays the same, but the passphrase protecting that key for the hardware encryption (not bitlocker) was changed - same difference for me ;-)

Comment: Do make sure that your hard drive is running with Encryption Enabled, otherwise the data is not actually encrypted. If you visit the post in the link I posted previously there is a screen shot of Samsung Magician. The container Encrypted Drive should read Enabled. If that is correct then your data is indeed secured because the drive encryption key is encrypted/decrypted with your ATA password.