# 2 questions re Self Encrypting Drives (SED)

Tags: encryption, sed, disk-encryption

1. Can the SED be “turned on” with documents and files already on the computer? Are they affected in any adverse way?
2. I have a laptop with SED that I’m wanting to use in a small work environment that uses a server and network. I’m thinking that since SED protects data at rest, encrypting the drive and using it in the network should not be a problem. Is this correct?

Comment: "I'm thinking that since SED protects data at rest, encrypting the drive and using it in the network should not be a problem." I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Basically I'm asking if there is a problem using a SED within a network that isn't "sharing the encryption," since it's on the drive. Will the laptop be able to "communicate" with the server if the data is sitting encrypted on the drive and the server isn't encrypted? Does that help my question make sense?

Answer (score 1):

2) The network will simply communicate as normal with the un-encrypted data. The drive automatically un-encrypts data when your operating requests it (and valid network requests). [SED Encryption introduction](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Introduction-to-Self-Encrypting-Drives-SED-557/)

Remember SED encryption offers about zero security while the PC is powered on. For it to be secure you need to power the device completely off.

Yes on some drives it looks like you can enable encryption after OS installation. See [How do I encrypt Samsung 840 SSD with Bitlocker?](https://superuser.com/questions/700009/how-do-i-encrypt-samsung-840-ssd-with-bitlocker/700236#700236)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. 2) Exactly why I wanted it protected--if laptop was taken, sensitive data would not be accessible.

Comment: 1) Perhaps my asking this will indicate my lack of understanding the BIOS, but would adding the password after programs and data on comp make all that inaccessible/unreadable? or would it not just be like adding or changing a password?

Comment: Yes on some drives it looks like you can enable encryption after OS installation.  See http://superuser.com/questions/700009/how-do-i-encrypt-samsung-840-ssd-with-bitlocker/700236#700236

Answer (score 1):

1) I **finally** rec'd a formal answer from Fujitsu, from whom I rec'd this laptop--Hybrid drive/SED, win7 Pro. This is in regards to encryption on computers that don't require additional software, which is done through the bios. Since it is done outside the OS, it does not affect files already on the computer. The answer given here was correct, but since this wasn't being done through bitlocker or in any way referenced in the response or other answers elsewhere on the site, I wanted to be sure.
2) And as so kindly answered here, there should be no problems when working in a network environment.  THANKS!!