# Bitlocker on Samsung 840 EVO SSD without TPM: Stuck on Password screen

Tags: ssd, encryption, bitlocker

I've a problem using Bitlocker to encrypt my Samsung 840 EVO SSD on Windows 10. When enabling Bitlocker the blue password screen before booting Windows freezes after inserting a correct password.

The details of my setup are as follows:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Installed in UEFI mode (I've checked this in  msinfo32)
- Samsung 840 EVO SSD
- No TPM available on motherboard (Asrock 970 Extreme mobo with latest firmware update)

I've followed the guide from another superuser question (https://superuser.com/a/700236/555167). This makes sure the "Encrypted Drive" option in Samsung Magician is enabled and Bitlocker can be used to fully encrypt the drive. After Secure Erasing the SSD (with Parted Magic) and reinstalling Windows 10 in UEFI mode the Encrypted Drive status is Enabled (see image).

[image: Samsung Magician]

Because no TPM is available in my computer, I've changed my computers policies to allow the use of Bitlocker without the use of TPM. After that the setup of Bitlocker could begin. I entered an encryption password and Bitlocker asked me to reboot to check the settings. During the reboot Bitlockers asks for my password, but after inserting the password, the blue Bitlocker password screen seems to freeze. It won't respond to any keys (ESC or ENTER including) and the only option is to power off the machine. I've tried waiting for more then one hour.

This freeze of the blue password screen of Bitlocker occurs every time I enter an correct password, when an incorrect password is inserted Bitlocker gives a nice warning, when ESC is pressed before inserting a correct password, Windows boots normally, but the encryption has failed.

Does someone now how this can happen? Is it an problem with the BIOS firmware, SSD or misconfiguration? Are there error logs I can check? If more details are needed please let me now.

edit: fixed. Windows Update KB3124200.

Comment: Does anything show up in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @KodyBrown Got a few warnings. No errors. The Warnings are (translated from Dutch)
24653: Bootmgr cannot retrieve Bitlocker mainkey for the volume from the password
and 24609: A key was not available from required sources during restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be that Windows Update was not working correctly. There was a bug in Bitlocker. This has been fixed in update KB3124200. The issue is resolved.