# BitLocker asks for recovery key every time on boot on SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, encryption, bitlocker

I did it:
http://www.ckode.dk/desktop-machines/how-to-enable-windows-edrive-encryption-for-ssds/
(enabled encryption using TPM module and BitLocker using SSD build-in encryption)
and after that I changed BIOS to newer version. After that, BitLocker asks for putting recovery key, what I did. It is asking now every time for recovery key, but additionally system drive is not encrypted (according to BitLocker). Samsung Magician says that the third encryption option is enabled.

manage-bde -status in CMD:

```
C:\Windows\system32>manage-bde -status
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.15063
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Disk volumes that can be protected with
BitLocker Drive Encryption:
Volume C: []
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 202,97 GB
    BitLocker Version:    None
    Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 0,0%
    Encryption Method:    None
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: None
    Key Protectors:       None Found

Volume D: []
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 215,43 GB
    BitLocker Version:    None
    Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 0,0%
    Encryption Method:    None
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: None
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:       None Found
```

[Samsung Magican](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwNQr.png)

Specification:

- Lenovo Y700 with TPM
- Samsung EVO 840 in GPT
- UEFI enabled
- Windows 10 Pro

When try to enable system partition, then everything is ok, until Bitlocker asks for choosing how much drive to encrypt, what is wrong, because I wanted to encrypt not using software but hardware encryption.

I don't know what I need to do. I worry about reinstalling windows, becouse I worry about losing key and possibility to use drive. There was similar problems with BitLocker askig for recovery key, but I didn't see problem with used SSD.

Comment: You should never update the firmware before you disable FDE. The solution is to use the recovery key, to turn it off (this will decrypt everything), then turn it back on.  **This is the only safe solution**, any other action (other then doing nothing and always using the recovery key), will risk data loss

Comment: Samsung Magician isn't going to identify Bitlocker, has FDE, it wants you to use the drives FDE capabilities, but I don't believe your model has that feature.  Sm is used for all Samsung products

Comment: So what tool should I use?

Comment: You can use Bitlocker.  You just need to do as I suggested.  Disable FDE then enable it again.

Comment: Now, I don't have recovery passwort at startup, but BitLocker doesn't see drive as encrypted. Actually here is similar problem [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1179832/did-windows-10-disable-encryption-without-authorization/1190534). Anyway, thank you for your help, I really appreciate that.