# SSD hardware encryption TCG/OPAL - desktop motherboard in 2024

Tags: desktop-computer, disk-encryption, samsung-ssd, tcg-opal

I have Samsung 980 PRO SSD which is [advertised](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/internal-ssd/980pro/) to support full drive encryption options like:
`AES 256-bit Encryption (Class 0), TCG/Opal,IEEE1667 (Encrypted drive)`
It's not a single case, this days a lot of SSD manufacturers are advertising similar capabilities.

Is there a way to somehow configure desktop system (BIOS) to enable and use those SSD capabilities? In my case I have [GIGABYTE X570S AORUS ELITE AX](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570S-AORUS-ELITE-AX-rev-11/sp#sp) motherboard, but my question is more general than that. If this motherboard doesn't support such a thing, is there any other manufacturer which does it? Please recommend.

I don't want to use Bitlocker or some other per OS level encryption method since I don't see the point of doing such a thing, especially for multi boot environments.

I'm also aware that there ware similar questions in the past without a clear answer, but those questions are really old and things could improve, hopefully.

Comment: If the BIOS/UEFI doesn't support hard-disk passwords, then you're out of luck. Asking for motherboards that support disk passwords is a hardware recommendation which is off-subject on our site.

Comment: When Samsung advertises hardware encryption, it means compatibility with BitLocker.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/700009/how-do-i-encrypt-samsung-840-ssd-with-bitlocker/700236#700236) seems like a duplicate, and just because you don’t want to use BitLocker, doesn’t mean it’s not a duplicate

Comment: @harrymc It's a AMI UEFI BIOS, nothing unusual here. I'm not asking for a specific hardware model here, just for an BIOS(software) example which have this functionality implemented. If you have it, e.g. in your mobo with Award bios running, I will be able to find specific hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound: I disagree about Samsung hardware encryption meaning BitLocker. The encryption in Samsung disks is done inside the disk controller. Samsung hardware encryption is always turned on for these models, just that the default password is blank, so needs to be set via the BIOS/UEFI. There is no dependence upon the TPM.

Comment: @harrymc There is no dependence on password in BIOS/UEFI either. Moreover, it doesn't guarantee disk encryption in any way.

Answer (score 0):

TCG Opal encryption is not dependent on BIOS in any way. You just use any compatible software to configure it, for example [sedutil](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/). You can find the detailed instructions [here](https://sedutil.com/#instructions).