# bitlocker on/off after uefi flash and recovery key has changed?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, encryption, uefi, bitlocker

Amendment: 
I noticed that though, BL is turned off, that when I try to use recovery options in Windows 10, or when I turn off and back on the TPM in UEFI, that the BL "recovery key" from the original FDE is still required to proceed.

Does this help in my quandry, as how to get BL turned on again, without being as whether I want to fully or partially encrypt?  (see below).

As an aside, I'm having what I believe is a separate problem, where the computer won't wake up from sleep,  I get  critical_process_died   and can't tell from the logs, what to try to fix .......sigh, perhaps, I should try a different Forum, if this one is so strict, that no one answers?

---

I am using bitlocker on a samsung 840 ssd and I disabled bitlocker to flash bios to 2.2 uefi, but when I re-encypt bitocker now it is giving me a different recovery key than I had before is this normal ?

I am also getting the "choose how much of your drive to encrypt" popup, which from reading here on Superuser ArsTechnica, it says should not happen if "all my ducks are in a row".

[How do I encrypt a Samsung Evo 840 SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/692172/how-do-i-encrypt-a-samsung-evo-840-ssd)

http://www.anandtech.com/show/6891/hardware-accelerated-bitlocker-encryption-microsoft-windows-8-edrive-investigated-with-crucial-m500

> "If everything is eDrive compliant you won’t be asked whether or you
>   want to encrypt all or part of the drive, after you go through the
>   initial setup BitLocker will just be enabled. There’s no extra
>   encryption stage (since the data is already encrypted on your SSD). If
>   you’ve done something wrong, or some part of your system isn’t eDrive
>   compliant, you’ll get a progress indicator and a somewhat lengthy
>   software encryption process."

Unfortunately I was asked if I want to encrypt all or part of the drive so I cancelled that.

So I am scared to go forward and overwrite, or bork, what had been working fine.

And/or each time I reencrypt "turn bitlocker on"  am I going to get a new key?

This is Windows 10 pro

Comment: "is this normal?" - Yes;  This is normal.  Once you remove the encryption from the drive, the recovery key is useless, which is the entire point.  Only somebody with the recovery key or the passphrase can remove the encryption from the drive.  Worth pointing out, if i am not mistaken, the recovery key only works on the same hardware that encrypted the drive.

Comment: Why not just pause/resume Bitlocker instead? You can do this from the Btilocker options in Control Panel, or from a CMD prompt with the `manage-bde` command.

Comment: actually, I don't recall removing the encryption, perhaps i did instead of pausing it.   i did make a mistake the 1st time i reflashed my UEFI, when I did not pause it, but since then, I believe it had been up and running, fine, and I did a pause and reflashed the UEFI again, as I have a ASRock Z170M-ITX/ac newer mb, they seem to update the UEFI often,  .........anyway,  the problem  NOW  is that I get  this  "whether or you want to encrypt all or part of the drive"  and I'm not sure how to proceed    ;

Comment: so that I won't receive  this message, which I don't believe I am supposed to be.less its only for initial encryption one is NOT supposed to be asked?